# Calculations VAT++ in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, math, calculated-columns, economics

I can't post the whole procedure here because it would be to confusing. What I am trying to do is calculating VAT. To do that I need to multiply `Share` with 0,25.

```
 select.....
    (SALES_PRICE * 0.8) as Revenue, 
    (SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount) as Share,
    (SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount) * 0.25 as VAT, 
    (SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount) + (isa.SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * (1-u.discount) * (0.25)) as Total
```

Edit: Got some great help and ended up with correct calculations and formatting. 
**Here is the result:**

```
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( sales_price * 0.8 )) 
       AS Revenue, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( sales_price * 0.8 * 1 - u.discount )) 
       AS Share, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( sales_price * 0.8 * 1 - u.discount ) * 0.25) 
       AS VAT, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( sales_price * 0.8 * 1 - u.discount ) * 1.25) 
       AS Total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` as decimal separator for `0.25`:

```
(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * (1-u.discount) * 0.25) as VAT
```

To get only 2 decimal places, you can do `CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,2), yourvalue)`.

To get the total, just multiply by 1.25 `(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * (1-u.discount) * 1.25)`

Comment: @Lebowski Here you go, but you should really ask about one problem per question.

Comment: Ok thats cool, i thought it would be better just to gather them up. Btw,  I tried your total query, its getting really wrong results (like -3427.000000)

Comment: Change it to  
`(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount) * 1.25 as total`
 and now it seems to work nice. Is this good formatting tho?

Comment: Without data, I cannot really say why.

Comment: btw, where can i add the convert?

Comment: Wrap the whole value, e.g. `CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,2), SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * (1-u.discount) * 1.25)`

Comment: Thank you for great help this early morning :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount * 0,25) as VAT
```

to

```
(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.discount * 0.25) as VAT
```

Also, you might want to make use of some brackets, let say something like

```
(SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * (1-u.discount) * 0.25) as VAT
```

Have a look at [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, i actually changed it to : 

`(isa.SALES_PRICE * 0.8 * 1-u.rabatt) * 0.25 as VAT`

Is that better? 

I also got a new question so please check if you have the time.